# Data transformation to experimental profiles, nested experiments, nested in respondents in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot, transformation

I am slowly working through a data transformation using R and the dplyr package. I started with unique rows per respondent. The data come from a conjoint experiment, so I have needed to head toward profiles (profile A or B in the experiment) nested in experimental iteration (each respondent took the experiment 5 times) nested in respondent ID.

I have successfully transformed the data to get experiments nested in respondent IDs. Now I have multiple columns X1-Xn that contain the attribute features. However, these effectively repeat attributes at this point, with, say, X1 including a variable for profile A in the experiment and X6 including the same variable but for profile B.

In the mocked image example below, I would basically need to merge columns v1a and v1b as just v1, v2a and v2b as just v2 and so forth, while generating a new column that delimits if they are from a or b.

Following up on the comments and helpful but not quite what is needed engagement with this original post, I have edited the post to include simple code for both the original data structure and the ideal outcome data:

```
#original dataframe    
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2) 
`Ex ID` <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3) 
v1a <- c(2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5) 
v2a = c(3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5) 
v3a = c(5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1) 
v1b = c(4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4) 
v2b = c(5, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4) 
v3b = c(5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5)
original <- data.frame(ID, 'Ex ID' , v1a, v2a, v3a, v1b, v2b, 
v3b)

#wanted data frame
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
`Ex ID` <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
profile <- c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b")
v1ab = c(2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5)
v2ab = c(3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2)
v3ab = c(5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4)
desired <- data.frame(ID, 'Ex ID', profile, v1ab, v2ab, v3ab)
```

I basically want to find a way to nest multiple variables within ID, experiment ID, profile IDs.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please share a reproducible sample of your data with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for engaging the post. I have edited it to include more details to help us drive toward an answer. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this with base R using `sapply`:

```
cols <- split(names(df)[-c(1,2)], substr(names(df)[-c(1,2)], start = 1, stop = 2))

cbind(df[c(1,2)], sapply(names(cols), function(col) {
    do.call(paste, c(df[cols[[col]]], sep = ","))
}))
```

Output:

```
  ID Ex_ID  v1  v2
1  1     1 2,4 3,5
2  1     2 4,5 4,2
3  1     3 5,5 5,2
4  2     1 1,1 2,4
5  2     2 3,5 1,1
6  2     3 5,4 5,4
7  3     1 4,4 2,5
8  3     2 1,1 5,4
9  3     3 4,5 1,2
```

data:

```
df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Ex_ID = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), v1a = c(2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4), 
v2a = c(3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1), v1b = c(4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 
4, 4, 1, 5), v2b = c(5, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at a minimal working example.

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),v1a=c(2,4,5,1,3,5),v1b=c(4,5,5,1,5,4))
```

To merge the columns v1a and v1b we can use the command `paste`, which concatenates strings. The new column is created using `mutate` which cames with the `dplyr` package.

```
df <- mutate(df,v1=paste(df$v1a,",",df$v1b, sep=""))
```

Result:

```
  ID v1a v1b  v1
1  1   2   4 2,4
2  1   4   5 4,5
3  1   5   5 5,5
4  2   1   1 1,1
5  2   3   5 3,5
6  3   5   4 5,4
```

If you want to get rid of the "old" columns v1a and v1b, you can use `select`

```
df <- select(df,- (v1a | v1b))
```

which results in

```
  ID  v1
1  1 2,4
2  1 4,5
3  1 5,5
4  2 1,1
5  2 3,5
6  3 5,4
```